# How to stop a TimerTask in Java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have implemented a TimerTask in Java and i need to stop the Thread after a period of time:

```
        .... 
        timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            int tweetCounter = 0;
            String message;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null && (tweetCounter < 100)) {
                        bucket.add(message);
                        tweetCounter++;

                        out.println("Number of messages: " + tweetCounter);
                        out.println("Nano Time: " + System.nanoTime());

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 30000);
        ......
```

At this point i try :

```
    timerTask.cancel();
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
```

After that nothing happens and the program never exits.
How can i stop the TimerTask thread?

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

will work .

> `int java.util.Timer.purge()`
>
> Removes all canceled tasks from the task queue. If there are no other
>   references on the tasks, then after this call they are free to be
>   garbage collected.
>
> Returns: the number of canceled tasks that were removed from the task
>   queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //this is the method you should use, not the Date(), because it is desperated.

            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//get the hour number of the day, from 0 to 23

            if(hour ==9){
                try{
                    listAllUsers();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("doing the scheduled task");
            }
            else{

                System.out.println(" Todays task already done");
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 0, 10000);// delay the task 10 seconds, and then run task after evey one minute
```

try this working for me